# Change the group of /dev/fb0 permanently [Embedded linux]

Tags: video, framebuffer, imx6

I am working on an embedded device (`arm imx6`), and i want the change the group of the `/dev/fb0`.

Actually it looks like by default the group of this file is `root` , but I want to change the group to `video`

So I added the following rule on `/lib/udev/rules.d/`

Name of the rule : **99-fb-permissions.rules**

Content of the rule:

`KERNEL=="fb[0-9]*", NAME="fb/%n", SYMLINK+="%k", GROUP="video", OPTIONS+="last_rule"`

to change the group for fb* nodes,

When I test this rule with : `udevadm trigger /lib/udev/rules.d/99-fb-permissions.rules` , I see that the group of `/dev/fb0` is correctly changed to `video`

```
crw-rw---- 1 root video 29, 0 Jul 25 09:24 /dev/fb0
```

But when i restart the system the group changes again to `root`:

```
crw-rw---- 1 root root 29, 0 Jul 25 09:26 /dev/fb0
```

Do you have any idea what could be the cause of this change ?
How can i identify the source of this problem?

Thank you in advance